# Does anybody know how to serve "opera9fixes.css" only to opera 9 through apache RewriteRule?

Tags: css, apache, mod-rewrite, user-agent

Does anybody know how to serve "opera9fixes.css" only to Opera 9 through apache RewriteRule? Thanks.

due to some mistake this doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera/9
RewriteRule main.css opera9fixes.css [QSA,L]
```

(both css are inside complicated directory structure)

Answer (score 0):

Opera 10,11 and 12 all have a version number that starts with 9.  It had something to do with a non-opera issue with version numbers of 10 or more.  I would change this to match anything that's not 9.8 but is 9.